# SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '$'. after upgrading to Dotnet 8 - Database Compatibility Version - Not EFCore UseCompatibilityLevel

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have an ASP.NET Core project which uses code-first in EF Core.
After upgrading from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and also EF Core packages I'm faced with an error

> SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '$'.

[image]

This is query from profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[id], [t].[idDatetime], [t].[IdDistPath], [t].[idLoadType], [t].[idLoader], [t].[idLoaderDriver], [t].[idShift], [t].[idTruck], [t].[idTruckDriver], [t].[level], [t].[pattern], [t].[Tonnage]
FROM [tbl_Loading] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[idShift] IN (
    SELECT [s].[value]
    FROM OPENJSON(@__shiftsAllIds_0) WITH ([value] int ''$'') AS [s]
)',N'@__shiftsAllIds_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__shiftsAllIds_0=N'[338769,338768]'
```

This is my `OnConfiguring` method:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
, o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(160));
}
```

I've tried to add another migration with .NET 8 and updated the database, but unfortunately it didn't work.

I've searched a lot in Stackoverflow community but none of threads are related to my issue.

Environment:

- .NET 8
- SQL Server 2022 Version 16.0.1000.6
- Windows 11

Comment: Can you dump the actually executed SQL, usig either a client or server side profiler?

Comment: @Charlieface I've updated and added profiler.

Comment: From your edit if you are using SQL Server 2022 then you need to look into why the compatibility level **of the database** is set to something less than 130 and see if that can be changed to something more up-to-date or not. You can see these with `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases`. Using `UseCompatibilityLevel(160)` won't help you if the database is set to use something lower. It will just generate incompatible syntax.

Comment: @Charlieface - not a dupe of that. That isn't even about EF core. The option of leaving the DB compat alone and using `UseCompatibilityLevel(120)` in the code is a valid solution to this question

Comment: @MartinSmith Fair enough, that's also a solution, but the real solution is to upgrade the compat level. There's probably a better dupe, I feel like I may have seen one in the past, you're welcome to find one.

Comment: yeah you're right, searching for `UseCompatibilityLevel` does find one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL generated has changed [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#contains-in-linq-queries-may-stop-working-on-older-sql-server-versions). `OPENJSON` requires SQL Server 2016+/compat level 130+.

See the mitigation options in the above article

> If the compatibility level is below 130 (SQL Server 2016), consider
> modifying it to a newer value ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16#best-practices-for-upgrading-database-compatibility-leve)).
>
> Otherwise, if your database version really is older than SQL Server
> 2016, or is set to an old compatibility level which you cannot change
> for some reason, configure EF Core to revert to the older, less
> efficient SQL as follows:
>
> c#
>
> ```
> protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
>     => optionsBuilder
>         .UseSqlServer(@"<CONNECTION STRING>", o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(120));
> ```

Before just upgrading the database compatibility level and getting on with your day you should be aware that some people are reporting [significant performance degradation](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/32394) with this new approach and not finding the old approach was "less efficient" than the new one. Due to potentially getting worse execution plans. You should test the performance implications of this change with your workload.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin Smith comment I've executed this query on `master` database

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
```

And saw that my database compatibility is **120** instead of **160**

[image]

Seems I should update my `database compatibility` first with this query

```
ALTER DATABASE DbTruckerWinAppV2 SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 160;
```

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: You can just accept my answer which already told you all this - that the two options are either to change the database compatibility level or use `UseCompatibilityLevel(120)` if that is not possible

Comment: I'm sorry, I've accepted answer dear @MartinSmith and @GertArnold but the right answer is ``ALTER DATABASE DbTruckerWinAppV2 SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 160;``